# Facebook style label on swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

As you can seeon the following image, The facebook has got an labels without texts. What was the trick for that kind of labels on ios with swift 2?

Screenshot:

[image: Facebook style label on load]

Answer (score 0):

The 'trick' is that those are not labels but custom views with animations.

Not quite tricky, though. You can put something like that together with about 20 constraints and about 8 views, as well as some gradient layers and animations on them.

**Edit**

On second thought, facebook might be using only layers for performance reasons and synchornization of the animation.

Comment: But it is not making sense to show those views which you created, before the label or image loaded. Any tricky thing for that?

Comment: It is making sense, as it works as a "wait a second, I'm busy loading content" user feedback and looks and feels better as text telling you that.

Comment: Yeah, but I am talking about the enabling disabling to much different layers couldn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand what you are trying to say. Could you [edit] your question and try to explain?